# Remembered selected field from a different page or previously saved in user account

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, jquery-ui

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can have a selected field showing if the selected field was previously selected on a different page. So if '.clicked' is active because selected on a different page then '.border' will have '.showBorder' active on the relevant field as per working example below

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".clicked");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index) {

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box) {
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });

   // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];


    if (index > 2) {
      info.style.left = 11 + ((index - 3) * 45) + 'px';
    }
    else {
    info.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    }
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';

    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");

  });

});


$(document).on("click", '.clicked', function(){
    $('.clicked').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:15px auto;padding:0;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline-block;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:15px auto;padding:0;}
.showBorder { border: 1px dashed #233354; }
.box-tip {
  display:inline;
  margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
  padding-left:10px;
 }

.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 90%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.numberCircle span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

li.selected {color:#fff;background-color:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-box">
  <li class="clicked">1</li>
  <li class="clicked">2</li>
  <li class="clicked">3</li>
  <li class="clicked">4</li>
  <li class="clicked">5</li>
  <li class="clicked">6</li>
  <li class="clicked">7</li>
  <li class="clicked">8</li>
</ul>
<div class="box-tip">
  <span class="info">Regular length for your collar size</span>
  <span class="numberCircle">?</span>
</div>
<ul class="box-sleeve">
  <li class="border">a</li>
  <li class="border">b</li>
  <li class="border">c</li>
  <li class="border">d</li>
  <li class="border">e</li>
  <li class="border">f</li>
  <li class="border">g</li>
  <li class="border">h</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on a different page"? Seems like you need persistent data, refer to http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/

Comment: @Ovais numbers 1-8 with class '.clicked' can be be selected on a page with a different URL, if 1-8 is clicked then I want the selection highlight to be carried over to current page therefore also border showing around letters a-h

Comment: I shared a link last time. You can store selection in local storage and then on target page retrieve and apply classes.

Comment: @Olivbelle when one of those options are selected, where is this selection saved? Cookie? Session data? Database? URL? Your scripts will have no way to know what the user selected previously if that data is not passed along. There are many ways to do that. Please clarify what methods you have available to you.